# Integrals $\int\frac{dx}{(ax+b)\sqrt{x^2+c}}, \int\frac{dx}{(ax+b)^2\sqrt{x^2+c}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Recently, I was given a question sheet with a lot of integrals. I could solve all of them except for a particular type of them:
\begin{align}
&I_1=\int \frac{dx}{(x+1)^2\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}=-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}{x+1}\\
&I_2=\int \frac{dx}{(x-1)^2\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}\\
&I_3=\int \frac{dx}{(2x+1)\sqrt{x^2-8}}\\
&I_4=\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}=\log x + \log\left(x+2+2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}\right)
\end{align}

($I_2,I_3$ also are expressible in elementary functions, but they are not *that* cute.)

The method that wolfram is using (trial pro subscription) is to complete the square inside the roots to transform them to $\sqrt{ax^2+b}$ and then substitute $x=\sqrt{{-b/a}}\sec x$ if $b$ is negative, and $x=\sqrt{{b/a}}\tan x$ if positive. Finally, it uses the tangent half-angle subsitution. I really don't think this is the best way.

The trigonometric substitutions seem to be unnecessary, since at the end we transform back the resulting trigonometric functions into a function that does not rely on trigonometry at all, e.g. $-\csc(\tan^{-1}x)=-{\sqrt{x^2+1}/x}$.

**Question**: Is there some easy way to deal with the integrals:
$$\int\frac{dx}{(ax+b)\sqrt{x^2+c}}, \>\>\>\>\>\int\frac{dx}{(ax+b)^2\sqrt{x^2+c}}$$
without the *trigonometric* and *Weiertrass* substitution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the type of $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{(ax+b)^2 \sqrt{cx^2 + dx + e}}dx$, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{ax+b} = t$ transforms into $\displaystyle \frac{at}{\sqrt{bt^2 + ct + d}}$ which can be reduced into standard integrals.

The same seems to work in linear case too.
$$\frac{1}{(ax+b) \sqrt{cx^2+ dx + e}} = \frac{at}{t \sqrt{bt^2+ct+d}} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{bt^2+ct+d}}$$

Comment: Yeap, that seems to be quite efective! And in the *linear* case, some ideas?

Comment: @chubakueno same seems to work in linear case too.

Comment: *Hiper-facepalms* Yes it clearly does. Thank you very much! I will wait a little more for answers and then accept yours :)

Comment: @chubakueno sure lol I didn't notice either :D

Answer (score 2):

Usually more direct, with $\sqrt {u^2 + 1},$ to take $u = \sinh t.$ With $\sqrt {u^2 - 1},$ to take $u = \cosh t.$ Tends to save several steps.

Relevant: it will still be necessary, to integrate a rational function of $\sinh x$ and $\cosh x,$ to use a stereographic projection. I worked it out:
$$  v = \tanh \frac{x}{2} = \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1}; \; \; \; \mbox{so} \; |v| < 1.  $$
$$  x = 2 \operatorname{argtanh} x = \log \left( \frac{1+v}{1-v}\right)   $$
$$  \sinh x =  \frac{2v}{1-v^2} $$
$$  \cosh x =  \frac{1+v^2}{1-v^2} $$
$$ dx =   \frac{2}{1-v^2} \, dv  $$

Comment: I have not studied hyperbolic functions yet, but I am open to ideas. Will this work with the first case?

Comment: After a little bit of google and wolframalpha I discovered the usefulness of those functions. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The Euler substitution $t=\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}-\sqrt{a}x$ for positive $a$ will reduce all these integrals to rational functions.

Comment: That would only work for integrals of the form $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$$, i think.

Answer (score 1):

Examples for Euler's first substitution, [one here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) suggests that $\large\sqrt{x^2+c}=-x+t$ with:
$$x=\frac{t-c^2}{2t},\hspace{0.2cm}dx=\frac{t^2+c}{2t^2} \hspace{0.5cm}\text{and}\hspace{0.5cm} \sqrt{x^2+c}=\frac{t^2+c}{2t}$$
Then
$$\int\frac{dx}{(ax+b)\sqrt{x^2+c}}=\int\frac{2\;dt}{at^2+2bt-ac}$$
$$\int\frac{dx}{(ax+b)^2\sqrt{x^2+c}}=\int\frac{4t\;dt}{(at^2+2bt-ac)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the second integral can be expressed in terms of the first
\begin{align}
&\int\frac{1}{(ax+b)^2\sqrt{x^2+c}}dx\\
=& -\frac{a \sqrt{x^2+c}}{(b^2+a^2c)(ax+b)}
 +\frac b{b^2+a^2c} \int\frac{1}{(ax+b)\sqrt{x^2+c}}dx
\end{align}
So, it boils down to evaluate
$$I= \int\frac{1}{(ax+b)\sqrt{x^2+c}}dx$$
for non-zero but otherwise arbitrary $a$, $b$ and $c$. To avoid domain dependent substitutions, let $t=\frac{ac-bx}{\sqrt{x^2+c}}$ instead to integrate for the distinctive cases below
\begin{align}
I&= \int \frac{1}{t^2-(b^2+a^2c)}dt\\
&=\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{-(b^2+a^2c)}} \tan^{-1}\frac{ac-bx}{\sqrt{-(b^2+a^2c)(x^2+c)}},& c< -\frac{b^2}{a^2}\\
\frac{a}{b(ax+b)} \sqrt{x^2-\frac{b^2}{a^2}} \,& c=-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{(b^2+a^2c)}} \coth^{-1}\frac{ac-bx}{\sqrt{(b^2+a^2c)(x^2+c)}},&  -\frac{b^2}{a^2}<c<0\\
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{(b^2+a^2c)}} \tanh^{-1}\frac{ac-bx}{\sqrt{(b^2+a^2c)(x^2+c)}},&  c>0
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Now, apply the solutions above to the four listed integrals

\begin{align}
&I_1\overset{y=x+1}=\int \frac{dy}{y^2\sqrt{y^2+1}}=-\frac{\sqrt{y^2+1}}{y}\\
&I_2 \overset{y=x-\frac12}=\int \frac{dy}{(y-\frac12)^2\sqrt{y^2+\frac34}}\overset{c>0}=-\frac{\sqrt{4y^2+3}}{2y-1}+\frac12\tanh^{-1}\frac{3+2y}{2 \sqrt{4y^2+3}}\\
&I_3=\int \frac{dx}{(2x+1)\sqrt{x^2-8}}
\overset{c<-{b^2}/{a^2}}=-\frac1{\sqrt{31}}\tan^{-1}\frac{16+x}{\sqrt{31}\sqrt{x^2-8}}\\
&I_4\overset{y=x+\frac12}=\int \frac{dy}{(y-\frac12)\sqrt{y^2+\frac34}}\overset{c>0}=-\tanh^{-1}\frac{3+2y}{2\sqrt{4y^2+3}}
\end{align}